# First start with sverchok. looking for feedback and how can i make this more efficient

Tags: node-editor, extrude, sverchok

I just started a project in Sverchok and before I continue, I would like get some feedback and hear how I can do this more efficient. It looks like a mess.

Do I need 3 Viewers, or do I use some list node for combining all parts?

The two faces extrude with the same matrix, but I want the extrusion to be on the same side of the x Axis. So for one of the extruded faces: 8 * -0.5 instead of 8 * 0.5.
I thought about making a mask list, mirror, copying all the vector information, but with each of them I run into more complex beginner problems.

Note that I have no prior programming/node experience.

[image: box extrude]

Comment: there are ways to join meshes, but it's not entirely clear to me what the end result is that you're looking for. Maybe you can do a quick 3d model of the result, and add it to the question. you might get answers that show how We (team sverchok) would approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me just insert the gist
https://gist.github.com/b846e86e59d5458d0b87abba5205f6b2
This example of some ways to solve issue. I don't know aim of your node tree.
First of all, you can use not only extrude to extrude. loft, copy with uvconnect, matrix tubes, simple pipe node or whatever you need. There are tonns of solutions depend of what you want.
Import json and test.

Comment: My aim is to make a parametric building block. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: there are many ways, maybe it must have some plane surface or something, that can define better exact way to generate.

Comment: I get some errors when importing the gist:
  File  “/sv_IO_panel_operators.py", line 203, in execute
    import_tree(ng, nodes_json=nodes_json)
  File “/sv_IO_panel_tools.py", line 819, in import_tree
    generate_layout('', nodes_json)
  File “/sv_IO_panel_tools.py", line 792, in generate_layout
    place_frames(ng, nodes_json, name_remap)
  File “/sv_IO_panel_tools.py", line 709, in place_frames
    ng.nodes[finalize(node_name)].parent = ng.nodes[finalize(parent)]
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Pipe (Surface)" not found'

location: <unknown location>:-1

Comment: update sverchok and import than

Comment: I can't view the second example in te gist, however I the other two helped to get better understanding of what is possible.